# Load success page content with AJAX content loader

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After clicking "submit" on my contact form, I want to use AJAX to load my `success.html` into a div (similar to the rest of my site) but I am having problems figuring out which specific AJAX/jQuery to use for this.

I'm trying:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
    $("#mainImage").load("success.html");
});
```

but to no avail.

Here is the AJAX I'm using to load the rest of my site into a `#mainImage` div:

```
$("#thumbs div").click(function(){             
    var toLoad = $(this).children('a').attr('href')+' #mainImage';
    $('#mainImage').fadeOut("fast",loadContent);
    window.location.hash = $(this).children('a').substr(0,$(this).children('a').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#mainImage').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#mainImage').fadeIn("1000");
    }
    return false;
});
```

And here is my PHP form that I direct to `success.html` after "submit" is hit.

```
<?php
ob_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $to =  "shubba4142@gmail.com";
    $subject = "BP Contact Form";
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];                
    $email_field = $_POST['email']; 
    $phone_field = $_POST['phone'];                            
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Phone: $phone_field\n         Message:\n $message"; 
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $body);
}

if (mail($to, $subject, $body)){
    header("location:/BP%20SITE-SHD/success.html");
} 

else {
    header("location:/BP%20SITE-SHD/error.html");
}

?>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: check firebug and see any js error is there ? is success.html same level as of the html page where you have the form ?

Comment: Just use load, like you do, to the php-script. It will redirect and make the output for either success or error depending on the outcome of the script.

Comment: @OptimusCrime do you mean I should do: 

`$("#submitButton").click(function(){
  $("#mainImage").load("html_form_send.php");
 });` 

because I did that and it still just loads the entire page success.html and not just the specified div

Comment: What are you trying to do? `.load` will take the entire webpage you call and output the content in the selected div. You will either have to change your html-file or change your php-file in some way.

Comment: @OptimusCrime what I'm trying to do is just place the div `#mainImage` from the success.html page and using `.load` have ONLY that div appear on the site. Right now, the entire page is loading. I'm trying to create a more seamless site that only has one div changing (like the rest of my site does) and the `#mainImage` div does a `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut`.

I'm wondering if because it's PHP it's not working the same/loading the same into that div as it would if it was an HTML page?